# C# reverse proxy after authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, proxy

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application that handles authentication among other things. I was hoping to be able to connect the client to another server after and only after a successful authentication happens programatically. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Is your web application a authentication provider?  In that case the other web application should take care to integrate with your application. It should redirect to your application if user is not authenticated. You should use  openid for this

Comment: It seems like you are Identity Provider. If so, [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) could be a good choice.